# Hybrid desktop/modern ui apps

Tags: windows-8

As far as I understand, Microsoft wants to allow "having both desktop and modern ui GUIs" only available for web browsers (am I mistaken here ?).

Does that mean common apps will be developped twice ? With e.g Skype being available both as pure desktop app and pure modern ui app ? And if a user installs both, these both instances will share no data ?

I can't imagine them doing a shift towards gesture friendly uis/hybrid ui, and leaving full blown desktop apps (not toy/phone-like/game apps, that can live in one space only) with no integration/entry points inside modern ui. Or maybe they want to participate in that "kill full-blown desktop apps" movement ?

So is there a model for a desktop app developped in whatever GUI toolkit, that wants to have some minimal integration with a small HTML/CSS/JS frontend in modern ui, like for e.g providing a dashboard of favorite or recently accessed files, contacts, etc ?

Answer (score 2):

Your first statement of "only in a browser" is not correct. Desktop applications don't change their current design paradigms. You can have browser-based apps on the desktop, of course. But full clients are still supported and still viable as a real solution to problems.

> Your takeaway from that comment should be that desktop applications are not deprecated as people assert. The reality is, desktop applications are still the only solutions to many problems.

Your second question of shared data is not correct. Skype shares lots of data with its app companion. Not because of shared local storage, however; it is because of the services that it shares. My account and contacts are on the server. So, they share a lot.

> Your takeaway from that comment should be that Windows 8 apps should not highly leverage local storage but should be built as service-oriented clients. To that end, your desktop applications should have already started to leverage this architecture, too.

Your third question (which is very cryptic) seems to be asking if a desktop application and a companion Windows 8 app can share or integrate with each other. The answer is yes. Not only can they share the same service, but file associates, custom protocols, and some of the non-Store manifest capabilities allow for this explicitly. Line of business applications should have a companion app, if you ask me. The integration points are many - though not every. But there is no other way to leverage the new capabilities of Windows 8 without introducing a companion app - even if that app does very little.

> Your takeaway from that comment should be that Windows desktop applications and companion Windows apps are the preferred and anticipated development approach.

Best of luck, thanks for the question.

Comment: I think you misunderstood his first question.  He was asking if browsers were the only type of application where you install a desktop app and then it provides an interface to act as a metro app as well - thus the browser reference (since I believe this is the only type of app that can do this).

Comment: Exactly. I was not not talking about apps available only in the browser, but about hybridation (desktop app + modern ui companion app) available only for web browsers.

Comment: I'm aware that a lot of skype happens on external servers, but I was talking of shared local settings. Skype may be a bad example for this, but I'm convinced there's still a big range of apps that could benefit from shared local data between Modern UI app and Desktop app.

Comment: You mention services, file associates, custom protocols, but what about local settings and data for non full-connected apps that still need them ? Btw, sorry for the cryptic, I'm not a native english speaker. If you have suggestions to rephrase it, i'll update my question.

Comment: The "need" for those features is going to be determined by your application and your needs. But they certainly are benefits to both types of applications.